# Broken Adobe CQ page rendering

Tags: adobe, aem, wcm

I am trying to get page (CQ 5.4):
htttp://localhost:4502/etc/replication/agents.author.html

But see the next:

```
Resource dumped by HtmlRendererServlet
Resource path: /etc/replication/agents.author
Resource metadata: {sling.resolutionPathInfo=.html, sling.resolutionPath=/etc/replication/agents.author}
Resource type: cq:Page
Resource super type: -
Resource properties..
```

In the 'system/console' > 'Recent requests' we can see render process.

```
0 (2013-12-16 02:33:09) TIMER_START{Request Processing}
      0 (2013-12-16 02:33:09) COMMENT timer_end format is {<elapsed msec>,<timer name>} <optional message>
      0 (2013-12-16 02:33:09) LOG Method=GET, PathInfo=/etc/replication/agents.author.html
      0 (2013-12-16 02:33:09) TIMER_START{ResourceResolution}
      1 (2013-12-16 02:33:09) TIMER_END{1,ResourceResolution} URI=/etc/replication/agents.author.html resolves to Resource=JcrNodeResource, type=cq:Page, superType=null, path=/etc/replication/agents.author
      1 (2013-12-16 02:33:09) LOG Resource Path Info: SlingRequestPathInfo: path='/etc/replication/agents.author', selectorString='null', extension='html', suffix='null'
      1 (2013-12-16 02:33:09) TIMER_START{ServletResolution}
      1 (2013-12-16 02:33:09) TIMER_START{resolveServlet(JcrNodeResource, type=cq:Page, superType=null, path=/etc/replication/agents.author)}
      1 (2013-12-16 02:33:09) TIMER_END{0,resolveServlet(JcrNodeResource, type=cq:Page, superType=null, path=/etc/replication/agents.author)} Using servlet org.apache.sling.servlets.get.DefaultGetServlet
      1 (2013-12-16 02:33:09) TIMER_END{0,ServletResolution} URI=/etc/replication/agents.author.html handled by Servlet=org.apache.sling.servlets.get.DefaultGetServlet
      1 (2013-12-16 02:33:09) LOG Applying Requestfilters
```

Used DefaultGetServlet instead of Page.jsp (**Using servlet org.apache.sling.servlets.get.DefaultGetServlet**)

All bundles are active.

```
Log outputs:
==> request.log <==
17/Dec/2013:01:29:49 -0800 [3677] -> GET /etc/replication/agents.author.html HTTP/1.1
17/Dec/2013:01:29:49 -0800 [3677] <- 200 text/html 3ms

==> access.log <==
<myIp> - admin 17/Dec/2013:01:29:49 -0800 "GET /etc/replication/agents.author.html HTTP/1.1" 200 1232 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36"

==> request.log <==
17/Dec/2013:01:29:50 -0800 [3678] -> GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1

==> error.log <==
17.12.2013 01:29:50.332 *INFO* [82.209.214.162 [1387272590327] GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl service: Resource /favicon.ico not found

==> request.log <==
17/Dec/2013:01:29:50 -0800 [3678] <- 404 text/html 6ms

==> access.log <==
<myip> admin 17/Dec/2013:01:29:50 -0800 "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 393 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36"
```

What have broken ? Why is it happened?

In bundles I found just next differencies (compare broken instance and a same one unbroken):

```
Day CRX Sling - Token Authenticationcom.day.crx.sling.crx-auth-token    2.2.0.54    cq5 Active
Day CRX Sling - Token Authenticationcom.day.crx.sling.crx-auth-token    2.2.0.61    cq5 Active
```

Also I have on my broken instance one more active bundle:
Day Communique 5 WCM Geometrixx Gocom.day.cq.wcm.cq-wcm-geometrixx-go   5.4.0
Turn it off, but it didn't help.

After that I uploaded cq-content-5.4.jar in the package manager, installed it, restarted system.
But again I have the same error (Resource dumped by HtmlRendererServlet) for all pages. It did not help too.

Comment: In the Felix console, are all of the bundles active? If so, could you post up any errors from the error.log file too.

Comment: All bundles are active.

Comment: By default, this page will be rendered out by Page.jsp and agents.jsp (/libs/foundation/components/primary/cq/Page/Page.jsp; /libs/cq/replication/components/agents/agents.jsp) — If you browse to these directly, are they both present? Are any other pages affected?

Comment: At first, Thank You for your help!
I browsed all these pages directly. They are present.
This situation happens with all pages, not only with /etc/replication/agents.author.html

Comment: OK, then it sounds like something is missing or changed within the core CQ library files, if it can't find a renderer for any page — I'd say check, 1) if you have the same number of bundles installed as a default instance (which is 308, on 5.6.1 from what I can see locally) — if not, what are the differences; If it does look identical, I'd try reinstalling the "cq-content-5.x.x.zip" package in CRX Package Manager — you'd have to be wary of that though, as if you've made any changes under the nodes included by the filter, you'd lose them. This question  is starting to get very localised though.

Comment: Compared and reinstalled, but it did not help

Comment: I faced the same issue today, but it was due to missing value in the sling:resourceType property in the nodes.

Comment: We moved to CQ 5.6.1 and do not face with such problems any more

Comment: I have the same issue on AEM 6.1 but none of the suggestions at the time of writing this comment worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

It also can happen due to settings in Apache Sling Resource Resolver Factory settings. We faced same issue and found that the setting for Resource Search Path is missing all entry. Verify the default entry should have following:

```
/aps
/libs
/apps/foundation/components/primary
/libs/foundation/components/primary
```

Answer (score 2):

I realise this is long after the fact, but perhaps it may be of use to future developers.

If you use the default GET servlet you need to configure a setting in the Apache Sling Get Servlet to render HTML. This can be found in the Apache Felix web console. You can access it here:

```
/system/console/configMgr
```

Then do a search for "Sling Get servlet". Inside your configuration you need to toggle the config setting for "Enable HTML" to select whether the HTML renderer for the default Get servlet is enabled or not.